# How can Qt Creator be used as general C++ IDE (no usage of Qt library)?

Tags: c++, qt, ide, cmake, qt-creator

I've been looking around for a nice C++ IDE, and I really like the features and performance of Qt Creator, and I plan to use it to make Qt based applications down the road. However, for right now, I just want to use Qt creator as general purpose C++ IDE without the use of the Qt library. How can I go about using Qt creator just for regular C++ development? What configurations do I need to make? I would appreciate some detailed guidance with this.

Thank you for your time and cooperation. I appreciate it, and I hope to hear from you all soon.

Comment: I'd say don't `include` any of the Qt libraries and you should be okay, but to be perfectly honest I've never really used Qt Creator so I don't know if there's more to it than that.

Comment: +1 Qt Creator is the best C++ IDE **regardless** of whether you're using it for Qt apps or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do it constantly.

You have two options:

1. use qmake project files: to get rid of all the remaining Qt stuff, add these to your project file(s):

   ```
   CONFIG -= qt
   DEFINES -= UNICODE QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT
   ```

   Remember that qmake itself is still required to build. So you'll most likely need a Qt installation.
2. use Cmake project files.

Both cases can count on Qt Creator's full support (for files and projects in the left pane). git and svn support in Qt Creator is awesome

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Mac OS X.  Perhaps check your `Applications` folder.

Comment: You can download the latest release of CMake from the CMake web site. http://cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

Comment: Type "which cmake" on the command line, and it will tell you where cmake is installed.  (Or any other executable that is installed.)

Comment: Just a tip: Qt Creator can be extended with plugins. In case something is missing (for example Makefile project similar to Eclipse, which doesn't support CMake out of the box) you can write your own extension. The Build and Run settings of a project along with the project wizard (which too can be customized to create very complex template projects) offer a lot of customization from custom executables, environment variables, command line arguments etc.

Answer (score 2):

I started using Qt Creator recently because I spend more and more time on my 13" laptop and just love the way it utilizes space. Other than that, it is feature-rich, fast, reliable and Qt isn't bad at all. As for C++ only IDE, it is more than welcome in my life.

The only other IDE that I love as much as Qt Creator is Code::Blocks. (I often switch between the two, depending on which machine I use)

Answer (score 1):

I did use Qt Creator for a non-Qt project once, but only for its code-editing features and code completion. I built the project and worked with the rcs from a separate terminal window. All I can say is that I was satisfied with Qt creator as a C++ code editor.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Eclipse forever as a Java programmer, so when I returned to C++, I continued to use it. However, Eclipse loses its brain ALL THE TIME, and I spend huge amounts of time trying to get it to stop being so stupid, issuing 100s of errors that aren't errors. As of today, I'm trying Qt Creator. So far, it's working well.

The Qt people have a quick reference that I followed: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-generic.html

Qt Creator doesn't have all the features I like from Eclipse, but it's working well for me so far. I can import my existing projects following these directions, then edit the files they list to smooth things out.

You have to, for instance, specify your include path by editing .includes.

I do builds and runs outside the IDE, so I'm not sure how well the Run button will work, but I'm sure you can make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt Creator with CMake on Ubuntu. I still usually compile in a terminal window so it really doesn't matter which build system you use. CMake's and qmake's project files just makes  it easy to import code files into the IDE. I'm also using GCC 4.6 from Ubuntu's repositories so it's newer and has better support for C++11 than the one that currently comes with Qt SDK. I have Qt Creator also installed from Ubuntu's repositories. Everything works so beautifully that I could cry.